# Select specific words

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How can I only select rows that contains column-Grade value like **Grade 1**, **Grade 10**, **Grade 11**, **Grade 12**... from the table?

Comment: With that data, what's the expected result?

Comment: just i need to select row of column Grade value like 'Grade 1'... i tryed Like case(Like '%Grade 1%').... but it returning Grade 1 with Grade 11

Comment: And those rows are? Can't you specify the result - instead of talking about like and stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Try somethink like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE Grade LIKE 'Grade 1%'
```

Comment: An `_` may be substituted for the `%` if only 1 character is desired, but it will only match Grade 10 through Grade 19, Grade 1 and any other Grade beginning with 1 (e.g. Grade 100) would not be included.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `grade` column value vertically like below

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Grade,'-',1) FROM table_name
```

and then after convert them to rows

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try like this

```
select * from tableName where SUBSTRING_INDEX(Grade,'-',1) = 'Grade 1';
```